# Silverstripe env variable value in config

Tags: silverstripe, silverstripe-4

I am trying to figure out if SilverStripe 4.2 supports referencing environment variables in the config files in a [similar fashion Symfony does](https://symfony.com/doc/current/configuration.html).

So far I was able to find the class responsible for building configs, which [doesn't seem to have this functionality](https://github.com/silverstripe/silverstripe-framework/blob/4/src/Core/Config/CoreConfigFactory.php#L132).

I thought of injecting another layer that would parse the YAML files and process the environment references, but it seems that you cannot extend a service since there is no Dependency Injection container available?

Is there maybe a different way to do this? All that I am trying to do is use environment variables in YAML config files.

Comment: are you looking for something different than [environment management](https://docs.silverstripe.org/en/4/getting_started/environment_management/)

Comment: ah after posting that i got what you are after.. can't say i have seen.. on silverstripe 3 iv overridden config settings with config.php if needed

Comment: Can you describe how did you do that? Is `config.php` the last config file loaded?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use environment variables in YAML config provided it's config for the Injector class. You can't use them outside of Injector config (as of 4.2).

You can wrap them in backticks for them to be parsed into config:

```
SilverStripe\Core\Injector\Injector:
  MyServiceClass:
    properties:
      MyProperty: '`ENV_VAR_HERE`'
```

Comment: Exactly this. I use this all the time since we use different variables during dev and production. Editing the yaml file every time would be pretty annoying.

Comment: this doesnt seem to work for me.  has something changed again?

Comment: Hi @Will, it might pay to ask a new question and provide example code and which version you're using etc